# Why is the InputStreamResource closed when I start reading from it?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc

I have a MongoDB, which stores a csv file, and two microservices (Spring Boot apps). One microservice handles file uploads and supports to get those files as a stream. The other microservice processes files. Those microservices are separated, because I maybe want to store files later in another way than in a MongoDB and I don't want to effect other services by this.

My problem is that when the file service returns the file as a InputStreamResource like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload/{importId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getUploadedFile(@PathVariable("importId") String importId)
        throws ImportFileNotFoundException {
    GridFSDBFile file = FileImportClient.getInstance().getFile(importId);

    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentLength(file.getLength())
            .body(new InputStreamResource(file.getInputStream()));
}
```

And I want to read from the stream it is already closed.

```
ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> response = restTemplate
            .getForEntity("http://upload-service/upload/" + importId, InputStreamResource.class);
BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getBody().getInputStream()));
for (CSVRecord record : CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(fileReader)) {/*toStuff()*/}
```

And I am getting a `java.io.IOException: Stream closed` caused by the parse method.

If I just `curl localhost:<port>/upload/<importId>` I get the whole csv file.
Does anyone know, why the InputStream is closed and how to fix that?

Stack trace:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:336)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:210)
at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:286)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:182)
at org.apache.commons.csv.ExtendedBufferedReader.read(ExtendedBufferedReader.java:60)
at org.apache.commons.csv.Lexer.nextToken(Lexer.java:89)
at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser.nextRecord(CSVParser.java:498)
at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser$1.getNextRecord(CSVParser.java:439)
at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser$1.hasNext(CSVParser.java:452)
at <mypackage>.<myclass>.process(<myclass>.java:71)
```

Comment: Did you check `ResponseEntity.body()` method? Maybe it closes your `InputStreamResource`

Comment: When I debug the response before the `getBody()` method is called, the description is "resource loaded through InputStream" and read is false. The `getBody()` method only returns the body and makes no changes.

Comment: Could you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Switch to `ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource>` instead. Probably you or the parser is reading mutliple times from the resource - which is apparently not supported.

Comment: It might sounds dumb, but could you try splitting for `(CSVRecord record : CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(fileReader))`
into 2 assignments : one for the iterator, the other for the loop ?

Comment: Splitting the assignments like Louis said has unfortunately no effect. Using a ByteArray works, but I would like to avoid using a ByteArrays, because my files are sometimes very large.

Comment: How large is "large"?

Comment: Sometimes about 100MB, but GBs could be possible too. It depends on the users needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution through this link: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7357

> [This answers my question] Note that you cannot simply return the InputStream from the extractor, because by the time the execute method returns, the underlying connection and stream are already closed
>
> [This fixes the problem] You can already read an InputStream by using the execute() method on the RestTemplate in combination with a ResponseExtractor implementation

I tried using the ResponseExtractor and now its working. It looks like this:

```
return restTemplate.execute(new URI("http://<myservice>/upload/" + importId), HttpMethod.GET, null,
            new ResponseExtractor<MyObject>() {
                @Override
                public MyObject extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                    CSVParser parse = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getBody())));
                    for (CSVRecord record : parse) {/*dostuff*/}
                    return new MyObject();
                }
            });
```